# Create database backup on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, backup

I'd like to have a link in my app, allowing me to download a dump of my database. (*à la* phpmyadmin, nothing gets saved on the server).

(I was thinking that I would use **php://temp** to avoid saving stuff on the server)

But how to create the dump file ? The way I see it I have two options :

**1 ] use system() and mysqldump**

```
$command = `mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] | gzip > db.sql.gz`;
```

**but how do I write the dump on php://temp ?**

**2 ] Create the file myself and write it to php://temp**

```
$tables = mysql_query ("SHOW TABLES");

while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($tables))
{
  $i = $i['Tables_in_'.$dbname];

  $create = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query ("SHOW CREATE TABLE ".$i));
  echo("\n# -------------------------------------------------------- \n");
  echo("\n# \n# Table structure for table `".$create['Table']."` \n# \n");

  echo("\n".$create['Create Table'].";\n\n");

  echo("# \n# Dumping data for table `".$create['Table']."` \n# \n\n");

  $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ".$i);
  if (mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
          foreach ($row as $j => $k) {
              $row[$j] = "'".mysql_escape_string($k)."'";
          }

          echo("INSERT INTO $i VALUES(".implode(",", $row).");\n");
      }    
  }
}
```

Which path should I take ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First option you should take

mysqldump is designed to take backup or create sql file for DB.

An example

```
    $command = "mysqldump -u ".USER." -p'".PASSWORD."'  ".DATABASE." ". $value."  -r \"".$backupPath."/".$backupFile."\" 2>&1";

    $res=system($command);
```

Comment: I forgot I could get system() return in a variable .. I could then write it to php://temp :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd also use the first option. Put it in a .sh file, make it executable and run it on a cron job as often as you like. I have something similar on my VPS which runs every morning at 9am.

Comment: A cron would be nice, but I'd like to be able to create a dump over the web, just by loging in my admin app.

Comment: Ah, yes. In that case using system($cmd) where $cmd is your mysqldump command makes more sense :)

Comment: exec() is even better, as I want the output of the command :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first option, save it to `/tmp` (or whatever) on the server and, after your command, add something like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/gzip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="db.sql.gz"');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
readfile('/tmp/db.sql.gz');
```

to start downloading it automatically.

Comment: "à la phpmyadmin, nothing gets saved on the server"

Comment: @Manu That´s not how I would do it, but you can of course just put your `system` command after the headers instead of the `readfile` function. By the way, I´m pretty sure phpmyadmin uses a file for `Export -> Save as File`; they'd have to, to avoid memory problems for large databases with not a lot of memory.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating a file so that I could avoid having a cron job to delete a /tmp folder.